# With ipython, renamed function can become double named. The module got both the old and new name

Tags: python, refactoring, ipython

No matter *reload*, *del*, *import* again, or *autoreload*, The function can be referred by two names, the old one works same as the new name.

To be clear, this is my codes:

```
#my_module.py
#...
#def waitting_user():  #This is the old name
#...
def waiting_user():  #this is new
#... see, I change the function name.
```

Then I can use both `my_moudle.waitting_user()` and `my_moudle.waiting_user` in the ipython console, they do the same.  The old name become a ghost name, it will stay with the running ipy. interpreter.  Any way to delete it when it happen?

Comment: You say that `waitting_user` is a correction of a typo in `waiting_user`. But isn't [waiting](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/waiting#English) with one 't' the more correct spelling?

Comment: Thank you for point out this.

Comment: Thank you for point out this. So, it's `waiting, or waitting`, both point to same function.  One is ghost of another, unless `del` by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any way to delete it when it happen?

`del` the name you don't want. i.e., `del my_module.waiting_user`

Answer (score 0):

You're not changing the name of anything. You're just creating two differently named functions. If you have a function defined with a bad name, you can just assign a new name to it, then `del` the old name as was mentioned above.

```
>>> def crap_name():
...     print 1
>>> good_name = crap_name
>>> del crap_name
>>> good_name()
1
```